# JOIN statement in Rails with OR condition across 2 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

UPDATE 2:

This looks much better:

```
Comp.includes(:members).where('members.member_email = ? OR comps.user_id = ?', current_user.email,current_user.id)
```

UPDATE:

This seems to work but is there a more elegant way to do this in Rails?  I feel like there must be.

```
@my_comps = Comp.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN teams ON teams.comp_id = comps.id LEFT OUTER JOIN members ON members.team_id = teams.id').where('members.member_email = ? OR comps.user_id = ?', current_user.email,current_user.id).group('comps.id')
```

ORIGINAL:

My model associations are:

```
Comp.rb
    has_many :teams
    has_many :members, :through => :teams

Team.rb
    belongs_to :comp
    has_many :members

Member.rb
    belongs_to :team
```

I want to write a query that finds all of the Comps where comps.user_id equals a particular value OR members.member_email equals a particular value for any of the members of that Comp.

I unsuccessfully tried this:

```
@my_comps = Comp.joins(:members).where('members.member_email = ? OR comps.user_id = ?', email, id)
```

There are 2 issues with the results returned: 1) it returns duplicate Comps where member_email is equal to the condition and 2) it does NOT return the Comps where the user_id is equal to the condition. I solved problem 1 by adding .group('id') to the end of this code but I feel like there is likely a better way to do it, and more importantly it doesn't solve problem 2.

Any advice on how to approach this differently?  Thanks so much.

Comment: The comps with the desired user_id (that you miss in the result), do they have at least one members record with a value (any value except NULL)? Otherwise that can be the reason I think - for issue 2.

Comment: No they don't.  And I was thinking something along those lines earlier as well but didn't know how to fix that.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed the suggestion, didn't know that `.join` only uses "INNER JOIN" in newer Rails (having an old version).
The final suggestions was: use `.include` instead of `.join`

Comment: Thanks.  I tried something similar earlier as well and it didn't work either.  I think ultimately what the problem was is that it needed to be a LEFT OUTER JOIN in order to get the records from the Comps table that did not have any Members.  I just posted a solution that seems to work but it looks too ugly to be the best Rails solution.

Comment: Can't you use include? that will use "LEFT OUTER JOIN" (at least in my Rails version). I changed my first suggestion because it wasn't good.

Comment: Yes, Include is a much better solution and works.  I'm a little new to rails and had not yet used that.  Thanks.